# jQuery inArray issue with combination with a each()

Tags: jquery, arrays, each

I am building a plugin which has a option where a user can set which element should right (default is left), the idea is for an menu, which has the option that a user can say, the first sub menu and the third submenu should float to the right, but i cant seem to get it to work, if i add one value it works, but once i add more values it doesn't work.

// plugin options

```
var defaults = {
    floatRight:      [1,5,6,9]
}
var opt = jQuery.extend(defaults, o);
```

// the loop

```
var i = 0
$('li').each(function(){
   if((jQuery.inArray(i, o.floatRight)) == '-1'){
      // add class...
   }
  i++;
});
```

Comment: "Does not work" how? Give a complete example, including your input and exactly what happens.

Comment: The first parameter passed to the callback function when using each is the current index, so you don't need to have your own `i` that you increment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you want to use `opt` rather than `o`?

```
$('li').each(function(i){
   if((jQuery.inArray(i, opt.floatRight)) !== -1){
      // add class...
   }
});
```

Also, change the comparison to `!==` as I'm assuming you want to add the class if it is floated on the right?

Example - http://jsfiddle.net/infernalbadger/JL7zx/

Comment: sorry my bad i typed to fast, but the o = opt ;-), yes this works now thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You don't need additional index and you are comparing `int` index with string `'-1'`.

```
var defaults = {
    floatRight: [1,5,6,9]
}

$('li').each(function(index){
   if((jQuery.inArray(index, defaults.floatRight)) == -1){
      $(this).addClass('float');
   }
});
```

code: http://jsfiddle.net/mtA4A/